# how to post collection of strings from excel to a restful endpoint

Tags: json, excel, vba

I have a collection of strings created by an excel macro, and a web application that needs to receive them.

I want to package these into a json dictionary so I can post them as a single parameter into a restful service I have running on the web app?

Answer (score 0):

Your question could use a little more detail for a more specific answer, but I'd recommend checking out [Excel-REST](https://github.com/timhall/Excel-REST) for working with web services in Excel.

```
Dim Client As New RestClient
Client.BaseUrl = "https://api.website.com/"

Dim Request As New RestRequest
Request.Resource = "strings"
Request.Method = httpPOST
Request.RequestFormat = json ' Automatically convert body to json

Dim Body As New Dictionary
Body.Add "strings", YourCollectionOfStrings
Request.AddBody Body

Dim Response As RestResponse
Set Response = Client.Execute(Request)

' -> POST https://api.website.com/strings {"strings":["a", "b", "c"]}
```